Deserializing FSharpX.PersistentHashMap<'k, 'v> with Json.NET
I'm looking for a way to deserialize FSharpX's PersistentHashMap<'k, 'v> with Json.NET.
The code:
...
let map = PersistentHashMap.add 1 1 PersistentHashMap.empty
let ser = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(map, Formatting.Indented)

printfn "%s" ser

let des = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersistentHashMap<_, _>>(ser)
...

prints:
[
  {
    "Item1": 1,
    "Item2": 1
  }
]

throws:
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
Cannot create and populate list type FSharpx.Collections.PersistentHashMap`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Context: I need to automate the serialization of a larger type which has several instances of the PersistentHashMap<'k, 'v> in it. I need a solution which works for generic persistent hash maps, since 'k and 'v are expected to change a lot.
I did manage to solve the problem for PersistentHashMap<int, int> with custom converters, but writing a new converter whenever 'k or 'v change defeats the purpose. I tried to create a generic converter:
override _.ReadJson(reader, objType, existingValue, serializer) =
    if reader.TokenType <> JsonToken.Null then
        if reader.TokenType = JsonToken.StartArray then
            let token   = JToken.Load reader
            let xs      = token.ToObject<List<'k * 'v>>()

            (PersistentHashMap.empty, xs)
            ||> Seq.fold (fun acc (k, v) -> PersistentHashMap.add k v acc)
        else PersistentHashMap.empty
    else PersistentHashMap.empty

But when used with the previous code, it fails with:
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
Unable to cast object of type 'FSharpx.Collections.PersistentHashMap`2[System.Object,System.Object]' to type 'FSharpx.Collections.PersistentHashMap`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]'.

Surprisingly, 'T list and Map<'k, 'v> work just fine.

Deserialization fails because PersistentHashMap<'T, 'S> lacks a public constructor that takes an argument of type  IEnumerable<'T * 'S> as required by Json.NET.  To work around this, you could create a custom converter for all PersistentHashMap<'T, 'S> types by using a little bit of reflection, like so:
type PersistentHashMapConverter() =
    inherit JsonConverter()
    static let ReadJsonGenericMethod = typeof<PersistentHashMapConverter>.GetMethod("ReadJsonGeneric", BindingFlags.NonPublic ||| BindingFlags.Instance ||| BindingFlags.Public);
    override this.CanConvert(objectType) = (objectType.IsGenericType && objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<PersistentHashMap<_,_>>)
    override this.CanWrite = false
    override this.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer) = raise (NotImplementedException())    
    // Constraints on T and S come from https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Collections/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Collections/PersistentHashMap.fs#L793
    member private this.ReadJsonGeneric<'T, 'S when 'T : equality and 'S : equality> (reader : JsonReader, t : Type, existingValue : obj, serializer : JsonSerializer) : PersistentHashMap<'T, 'S> =
        match serializer.Deserialize<System.Collections.Generic.List<'T * 'S>>(reader) with with
        | null -> PersistentHashMap.empty // TODO: decide whether to return null, return empty, or raise an exception.
        | l -> l |> PersistentHashMap.ofSeq
    override this.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer) =
        let keyValueTypes = objectType.GetGenericArguments()
        ReadJsonGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(keyValueTypes).Invoke(this, [| reader; objectType; existingValue; serializer |])

The trick here is to create a generic method ReadJsonGeneric<'T, 'S>(...) for reading a map with the given key and value types, and then, from inside ReadJson(), to invoke it using MakeGenericMethod() using the generic arguments of the incoming objectType
Once the converter is defined you can add it to settings as follows:
let settings = JsonSerializerSettings()
settings.Converters.Add(PersistentHashMapConverter())

let ser = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(map, Formatting.Indented, settings)

let des = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersistentHashMap<int, int>>(ser, settings)

Notes:

Since PersistentHashMap<'T, 'S> does not implement IReadOnlyDictionary<'T, 'S> but does implement IEnumerable<'T * 'S> the serialization will be as an array of tuples, as you have noticed:
[
  {
    "Item1": 1,
    "Item2": 1
  }
]


There is no need to load the contents of the reader into a JToken hierarchy, then deserialize the JToken to a List<'k * 'v>.  Deserializing directly to List<'k * 'v> will be more performant as it avoids the intermediate JToken representation.


Mockup fiddle here.

Thanks. This works if I remove the null check. Otherwise it doesn't compile and raises The type 'List<'T * 'S>' does not have 'null' as a proper value. I'm using F# 8.0.200 and .NET 4.8. Do you know why this happens?

@StefCor - I think it's because I (unintentionally) used System.Collections.Generic.List<T> as my intermediate type, and null is possible for this type.  And also JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(reader) is declared to return a nullable T?.  Will update.

@StefCor - Did using System.Collections.Generic.List<T> explicitly resolve your compiler error?

Yes. I didn't realize that List<'T> was actually FSharp.Collections.list<'T>.

Your generic converter works fine for me (with a few minor changes):
open FSharpx.Collections
open Newtonsoft.Json
open Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

type PersistentHashMapConverter<'k, 'v when 'k : equality and 'v : equality>() =
    inherit JsonConverter()

    override _.CanConvert(objectType) =  true

    override _.CanRead = true

    override _.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer) =
        failwith "not implemented"

    override _.ReadJson(reader, objType, existingValue, serializer) =
        if reader.TokenType <> JsonToken.Null then
            if reader.TokenType = JsonToken.StartArray then
                let token   = JToken.Load reader
                let xs      = token.ToObject<List<'k * 'v>>()

                (PersistentHashMap.empty, xs)
                ||> Seq.fold (fun acc (k, v) ->
                    PersistentHashMap.add k v acc)
                :> _
            else PersistentHashMap.empty
        else PersistentHashMap.empty

let deserialize<'k, 'v when 'k : equality and 'v : equality> ser =
    let converter = PersistentHashMapConverter<'k, 'v>()
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersistentHashMap<'k, 'v>>(ser, converter)

let map = PersistentHashMap.add 1 1 PersistentHashMap.empty
let ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(map, Formatting.Indented)
let des = deserialize<int, int> ser
printfn "%A" des

You just have to make sure you create a converter of a type that matches the HashMap. I've added a deserialize function that does that for you automatically.

Thanks. This does indeed work, but only if I specify the generic types of the converter, which defeats the purpose. It throws the stated error if let converter = PersistentHashMapConverter<_,_>().

See my updated answer. You can't create the converter in a vacuum - it has to match the type of the HashMap. I've created a helper function that does that for you automatically if you have a HashMap of the desired type. If not, it's no surprise that you have to specify <int, int> for both the HashMap and the converter.

This just creates a function which carries over the initial problem. You can actually create the converter in a vacuum by using reflection, which the other answer shows. That's what I needed, and it works.

You still have to specify the HashMap type of <int, int> at the time of deserialization, so it puzzles me why you need a typeless converter, but if you’re happy with the other answer, that’s fine.

Ok, now I understand what you mean. In my code, I'm not actually calling JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersistentHashMap<'k, 'v>>, but do the deserialization of a record type which contains several hashmap instances. This hides the generic type parameters, and that's why the other solution is more convenient for me. Still, your answer helped me better understand what I was doing, hence the +1. Thanks again.
